# Microservice Migration from Deployment per tenant to Single deployment for all Tenant

Tags: architecture, microservices, kubernetes-helm, multi-tenant

In Current Setup -:

- We have single DB in cloud for all Tenant having segregation of data within table on tenant basis.
- Individual deployment per tenant(separate Kubernetes space) on cloud of all the microservice.

New Setup

- I need single deployment for all the tenant in same Kubernetes namespace.(This can be easily achieved)
- I need the ways in which i can manage the configuration(inside application.yaml) of different microservices which are as of now have different values for different tenant as they are deployed in different Kubernetes namespace, But now we have single deployment for all the tenant.

What could be the different ways to achieve this ? Managing the different configuration for different tenant in single deployment.

Tech Stack of micros

- tomee for rest api in micro
- java
- application.yaml in Kubernetes ConfigMap for all microservices.